# All of these words feature

Tags: lucene

I have a "description" field indexed in Lucene.This field contains a book's description.
How do i achieve "All of these words" functionality on this field using BooleanQuery class?
For example if a user types in "top selling book" then it should return books which have all of these words in its description.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two pieces to get this to work:

1. You need the incoming documents to be analysed properly, so that individual words are tokenised and indexed separately
2. The user query needs to be tokenised, and the tokens combined with the `AND` operator.

For #1, there are a number of Analyzers and Tokenizers that [come with Lucene](http://hudson.zones.apache.org/hudson/job/Lucene-trunk/javadoc/) - have a look in the `org.apache.lucene.analysis` package. There are options for many different languages, stemming, stopwords and so on.

For #2, there are again a lot of query parsers that come with Lucene, mainly in the `org.apache.lucene.queryParser` packagage. `MultiFieldQueryParser` might be good for you: to require every term to be present, just call

```
QueryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR)
```

[Lucene in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394281), although a few versions old, is still accurate and extremely useful for more information on analysis and query parsing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you add all query parts (one per term) via

```
BooleanQuery.add(Query, BooleanClause.Occur)
```

and set that second parameter to the constant `BooleanClause.Occur.MUST`, then you should get what you want. The equivalent query syntax would be "+term1+term2 +term3 ...".